# Unitarity in the 't Hooft limit

Tags: quantum-gravity, ads-cft, unitarity, holographic-principle, supergravity

Consider a quantum gauge theory with a holographic dual at infinite $N$ and 't Hooft coupling, in which the gauge theory is described by classical (super)gravity.

If I initialize the system in a pure state describing gravitational collapse, then a black hole will subsequently form, but it will not Hawking radiate (since it occurs in classical gravity). On the other hand, by the AdS/CFT dictionary, a BH background is supposed to describe a thermal state. Thus we have seemingly evolved from a pure state to a permanently mixed state. How is this consistent with unitarity?